# Android Application Crash | InTune Wrapper or SDK

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, intune

We are facing issue in android application developed using Xamarin forms. Normal APK is working fine, But facing crash issue when launching the app after build is wrapped using InTune wrapper tool.

We followed below two way to convert the InTune supported application.

Wrapped the application using the InTune wrapper tool after successfully create the APK in release mode. The steps are available in the below link to wrap the application.

//learn.microsoft.com/en-us/intune-classic/deploy-use/prepare-android-apps-for-mobile-application-management-with-the-microsoft-intune-app-wrapping-tool

Integrated InTune SDK for Xamarin forms android application available as a Nuget package (Microsoft.InTune.MAM.Remapper.Tasks). Followed the steps which are available in the below link.

1.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/intune-classic/develop/intune-app-sdk-xamarin#enabling-mam-in-your-android-mobile-app /

2.https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/Microsoft.Intune.MAM/true

When trying the first way, the app did not launch and crashed. Please let me know if the second method is the correct approach and if it can be used to create apk for InTune environment.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the second link.App wrapping tool is not supported for the xamarin android apps.Instead you need to integrate the sdk provided from Intune.
Please look into the below docs.It may help.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/intune/app-sdk-xamarin

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin.Forms do not support wrapping for Android at all. I have had loads of trials and talks with Microsoft guys themselves for about 2 months. This is due to usage of the Remapper package. you need to integrate with the Intune SDK. Only then can you launch it under the company portal.

Hope this helps.